# Blazor JSInterop static vs instance C# methods

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

Could somebody please let me know how static methods work in regard to calling C# methods from JavaScript using JS interop?

If I have a static method in the code section of a component that references objects in that component, and there are multiple instances of that component on a page, will all instances be affected by the method call?

Or even worse, will this act as a Singleton on my server causing updates to every single client instance of that component?

I'm currently developing an audio recording system that cycles through phrases marked in text, and whenever JavaScript detects 5 frames of silence in the media stream, I want to call a C# method that will highlight the next section of text by changing its CSS class.

Comment: The documentation [Call .NET methods from JavaScript functions in Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0) explains it well along with example code.

Comment: No, I don't think it does answer the questions I just asked at all. I wrote them after reading that page. The information and examples on that page show how to provide an instance reference from .net to JavaScript, but it does not explain what happens if you attempt to use the static method to modify markup in a component that might have multiple instances. I'm quite sure that I will end up passing instance references into JavaScript, but I still want to know exactly what happens if you use a static method in that way.

Comment: `If I have a static method in the code section of a component that references objects in that component` This doesn't make sense because static methods cannot reference objects of a component. Please show an example of what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't put very well. The example showed in the page that you linked demonstrates returning values from the C# method, but not directly manipulating anything in the markup of the component. But now that we talk about it, I suspect I will probably just get a compiler error if I refer to any variables that are non static from within the static method. Actually, I currently have a broken arm-- so I can do searches and ask questions using speech to text, but typing code to see what will happen is hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change some styles in your component, you definitely not want to use a static method. Because a static method **could not interact with the instance of the component** - as you cannot use the `this` keyword in a static method.

What I think you want to do is first, in C# side, create a classic method in your component C# code. For example create:

```
public void ChangeStyle() 
{
     this.ClassToDisplay = DoSomeManipulation();
}
```

Then, JS will need the instance of the the component. So you can do something like that: (I use the `OnAfterRenderAsync` because it is shown in Microsoft documentation, but the goal is to do it once)

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        DotNetObjectReference<MyComponent>? dotNetHelper = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("JSFile.setDotNetHelper", dotNetHelper);
    }
}
```

Then in JS side, you will need the `setDotNetHelper` method, with the following content:

```
class JSFile
{
    static dotNetHelper;

    static setDotNetHelper(value)
    {
        JSFile.dotNetHelper = value;
    }
}
```

Now you are ready, you can call whenever you want the `ChangeStyle` method of your component. To do so, use this instruction in JS:

```
await dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('ChangeStyle');
```

Et voilà. I am available for clarifications or questions, have a good one!

// Dylan

Comment: I've done almost this exact thing and am still having issues with having multiple instances of the component on the same page, only the last  component works.  Please see my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77391437/blazor-server-app-js-interop-call-within-a-reusable-component-not-working-when